# Loop i++ vs i+=2

Tags: java

I've been trying to make an efficient algorithm for finding prime numbers and as part of my attempts I have been using the following code.  I have a thought for speeding up the loop by changing the incitement to i+=2 but this actually making this change seems to add 2 seconds to the run time of my program.  Can anyone explain why this happens, as it seems that the loop would have to do half as work work to complete?

```
for(int i = answers.get(answers.size()-1)+2;i<n;i++) {
        int bit = i%64;
        int currentInt = i/64;

        int isPrime = (primes[currentInt] >> bit) & 1;
        if(isPrime == 1) {answers.add(i);}
    }
```

Full code below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Primes15 {
  static Long start;

  public static IntStream stream() {
    int numbers = 15350808;
    int n = 982451712;
    List<Integer> answers = new ArrayList<>();
    long[] inverseShifts = new long[64];
    long temp = 1;

    for(int i = 0; i < inverseShifts.length; i++) {
      inverseShifts[i] = temp ^ -1;
      temp = temp << 1;
    }

    long[] primes = new long[numbers+1];
    primes[0] = -6148914691370734930L;
    for(int i = 1;i<primes.length; i++) {
      primes[i] = -6148914691370734934L;
    }

    System.out.println("Setup taken " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + "  millis");
    start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    for(int p =3; p*p <=n; p+=2) {
      int bit = p%64;
      int currentInt = p/64;
      long isPrime = (primes[currentInt] >> bit) & 1;
      if(isPrime == 1) {
        answers.add(p);
        int cPrimeSquared = p*p;
        int change = (p==2)? p : p+p;
        for(int i = cPrimeSquared; i <= n; i += change) {
          int innerBit = i % 64;
          int innerInt = i /64;
          isPrime = (primes[innerInt] >> innerBit) & 1;
          if(isPrime == 1) {
            primes[innerInt] = primes[innerInt] & inverseShifts[innerBit];
          }
        }
      }
      System.out.println("finder took " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + "  ms");
      start = System.currentTimeMillis();
      for(int i = answers.get(answers.size()-1)+2; i<n; i++) {
        int bit = i%64;
        int currentInt = i/64;
        long isPrime = (primes[currentInt] >> bit) & 1;
        if(isPrime == 1) {answers.add(i);}
      }
      System.out.println("search took " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + "  ms");
      start = System.currentTimeMillis();

      return answers.stream().mapToInt(i->i);
    }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    stream();
    Long finish = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Time taken " + (finish - start) + "  millis");
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please include your `answers`, `primes`, and `shifts` declarations?

Comment: I've actually changed that line will update.  answers is declared empty but it has already had a number of primes added everyone up to 31337.  primes is an array of longs there are 15350809 numbers in it at this point.  shifts is an array of 64 long numbers the first being 63 0's followed by 1 and every one is shifted by place so (1, 10, 100, etc).

Comment: I mean i+=2 which is a shorter way of writing i=i+2

Comment: given code should not even compile (assuming `primes` is really a `long[]`) - missing cast to int; `shifts` is not being used at all (posted/edited code); we have no idea how the time was taken; please post [mcve] and add additional information to question, not (just) as comment

Comment: After 2 there are no even primes just odd ones.  All even number are divisible by 2.

Comment: @LexMan I know, I thought you were using the size of the answer to look not the value at the end.

Comment: I think you should profile it, it isn't even clear that the issue lies in the loop.

Comment: If you want us to read your code please reformat it to remove that excessive whitespace.

Comment: Do you want to *find a prime numbers* or *check if given number is prime or not*?

Comment: Btw, it seems as if you're only adding elements to `answers` except for `answers.get(answers.size()-1)` - thus you might want to consider making `answers` a `LinkedList`. That would get rid of the need to resize the list once it is full and even getting the last element would be quite fast because `LinkedList` would iterate backwards which means exactly one iteration.

Comment: @Thomas I tried using a LinkedList but it actually took longer.  A linked list took 31 seconds while ArrayList took 17 seconds.  I'm not really sure why that happens either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some testing with JMH - since the whole code was missing and still hard to read, I used a simplified, naive  version (not usable to find primes, but with similar calculations IMHO):

```
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
public class Increments {

    private long[] primes;

    @Setup
    public void setup() {
        primes = new long[] {3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23};
    }

    @Benchmark
    @Fork(1)
    public List<Integer> inc() {
        List<Integer> answers = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 3; i < 100; i++) {
            int bit = i % 32;
            int cur = i / 32;
            long test = (primes[cur] >> bit) & 1;
            if (test == 1) {
                answers.add(i);
            }
        }
        return answers;
    }

    @Benchmark
    @Fork(1)
    public List<Integer> addOne() {
        List<Integer> answers = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 3; i < 100; i+=1) {
            int bit = i % 32;
            int cur = i / 32;
            long test = (primes[cur] >> bit) & 1;
            if (test == 1) {
                answers.add(i);
            }
        }
        return answers;
    }

    @Benchmark
    @Fork(1)
    public List<Integer> addTwo() {
        List<Integer> answers = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 3; i < 100; i+=2) {
            int bit = i % 32;
            int cur = i / 32;
            long test = (primes[cur] >> bit) & 1;
            if (test == 1) {
                answers.add(i);
            }
        }
        return answers;
    }
}
```

Results (5 warmup iterations, 5 measurement iterations):

> ```
> Benchmark          Mode  Cnt    Score    Error  Units
> Increments.addOne  avgt    5  304,670 ± 73,226  ns/op
> Increments.addTwo  avgt    5  131,429 ± 13,616  ns/op
> Increments.inc     avgt    5  249,329 ± 14,866  ns/op
> ```

that is, sorted by nanoseconds per operation:

> ```
> i+=2  131ns
> i++   249ns
> i+=1  304ns
> ```

kind of expected: increment by 2 is 2 times faster; a bit of surprise, `i += 1` is a bit slower than `i++` - I would have assumed that the compiler creates the same opcode for both

<sub>first contact with JMH, not sure if I did it 100% 
correctly, but had to test it [:-)</sub>